# clickable css menu without JS

Tags: html, css

i want to create an HTML5 menu with CSS which works with click instead of hover.
I saw examples on the web where its done with JS.
I was wondering if it's possible to do it without JS. one way maybe is to add

```
 <input type='checkbox' />
```

before each parent and according to if its checked to show the sub items
what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `:checked`

Yes you can do it using a checkbox, it isn't that well supported currently though. It uses the next sibling `+` and general sibling `~` selectors along with `:checked`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/W9xKc/)

**HTML**

```
<input id="menu-button" type='checkbox' />
<label for="menu-button"></label>
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Menu item 1</li>
    <li>Menu item 2</li>
    <li>Menu item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* hide the checkbox */
 #menu-button {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
}
#menu-button + label:after {
    display:block;
    content:"v";
}
#menu-button:checked + label:after {
    content:"^";
}
#menu {
    display:none;
}
#menu-button:checked ~ #menu {
    display:block;
}
```

### `:target`

Another way is to use `<a>` tags and `:target`, this is also not that well supported.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/tsR73/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#menu">Show menu</a>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu item 1</li>
        <li>Menu item 2</li>
        <li>Menu item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">Hide menu</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu {
    display:none;
}
#menu:target {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Well I care very little about IE7 and IE8 support these days but they're still like 8-10% or so market share so it's up to you whether to drop that or not. I'm quite fond of the `:checked` method but a JavaScript solution would probably be the safer bet.